# JPanel cropping or (.setBounds()) not working

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, null-layout-manager

Sometimes the setBounds() works but only in the actionlistener.
my code: 
-does not work

```
public panel() {
    initComponents();
    setBounds(100,100,105,105);
    setMaximumSize(new Dimension(100,100));

}
```

-does work

```
private void btnBestellingItemToevActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                      
    setBounds(100,100,105,105);
    setMaximumSize(new Dimension(100,100));


}
```

-layout manager:

```
javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
    this.setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(btnBestellingItemToev, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 89, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                    .addComponent(txtWat, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(txtTafelNr, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 80, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
            .addGap(0, 131, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
```

Can anyone help me so it works in the constructor also?

Comment: setBounds() works always as its constants are declared, then isn't true at all

Comment: is there a layout manager setup in the containing window/frame?  It probably readjusts everything after the ctor.

Comment: javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);

Comment: The likely cause is you are fitting the layout manager, you call `setBounds` and something causes the layout manager to re-layout the component as it see fits.  The question is, why are you calling `setBounds`?

Comment: to set the position and the size in time

Comment: That's very little information to go on.  The cause of your problem is the fact that the container you component is in is under the control of a layout manager, the solution will be based on your needs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said, the problem you're having is the fact that the container the component you are trying to move/size has a layout manager on it.

The layout manager is responsible for determining the position and size of all the components within in it.

You have two choices.  Write your own layout manager that does what you want it to do.  This is reasonably complex process, but is generally a better choice or do without a layout manager.

Personally, when doing things like this, I paint the result directly to the panel, but that's me...

[image: BeachBallOfDoom]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class BouncyBall {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new BouncyBall();
    }

    public BouncyBall() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new BallCourt());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class BallCourt extends JPanel {

        private JLabel beachBall;
        private int delta = 4;

        public BallCourt() {
            setLayout(null);
            beachBall = new JLabel();
            try {
                beachBall.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/BeachBallOfDoom.png"))));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            beachBall.setBounds(0, 100 - 16, 32, 32);
            add(beachBall);

            Timer timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    int x = beachBall.getX() + delta;
                    if (x + beachBall.getWidth() > getWidth()) {
                        delta *= -1;
                        x = (getWidth() - beachBall.getWidth()) + delta;
                    } else if (x < 0) {
                        delta *= -1;
                        x = delta;
                    }

                    beachBall.setLocation(x, beachBall.getY());
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }

}
```